# how to replace non-ascii Western Latin characters like '┌''├''⌐''┐''┴' in xml c#

Tags: c#, non-ascii-characters

how to remove non ASCII characters like inverted ''T'' , "L" etc, in xml c#

I have tried Sanitize Xml String like

```
(character >= 0x20 && character <= 0xD7FF) ||
(character >= 0xE000 && character <= 0xFFFD) ||
(character >= 0x10000 && character <= 0x10FFFF)
```

And used Regex as below:

```
Regex.Replace(inputText, @"[^><#\w\.@-]", "");
(or)
string str = str.replace(/[^A-Za-z 0-9 \.,\?""!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)-_=\+;:<>\/\\\|\}\{\[\]`~]*/g, '')
```

And Pattern replace as below:

```
string pattern = @"#x((10?|[2-F])FFF[EF]|FDD[0-9A-F]|7F|8[0-46-9A-F]9[0-9A-F])";
```

And finally with

```
XmlConvert.VerifyXmlChars(text);
```

But no use, characters looks like below:
'┌''├''⌐''┐''┴'

Please see this link
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Latin_character_sets_%28computing%29

└   U+2514              C0  C0
┘   U+2518              D9  D9

Please, help me out of this. Thanks in advance

Comment: You already had a working answer (at least if you do not need to handle very corner cases) in (now deleted) Dmitry's answer. If you need only **ASCII** characters then leave out anything > 127 and you're done. BTW talking about "western latin character sets" and "ASCII" is misleading (IMO). One or the other. BTW you may want to read about https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try This

string s = "søme string";
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Sorry, not working. string s = "søme string"; In this string you can paste the char 'ø'. But the string which I'm getting is having the chars, which can't be pasted, it can be visible either in notepad or in browser after rendering.

Comment: The chars in my string is like invert 'T' , inverted 'L' etc,